# TimePicker C# XAML UWP Width Customization

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, timepicker

I'm trying to customize the TimePicker control Width without so much success. It has HH and MM but the problem is that each one of them uses 2 or 3 times more space than is indeed needed to hold a number like "22".

[image: e.g. in this image]

Does anyone have any idea how to customize it? I imagine I must change the MinWidth or Padding maybe.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

After testing, I saw that I need to define for e.g. the Grid MinWidth=10 and MaxWidth=150 on the bottom of the style tree as shown below. The issue is that after that, there are many other definitions. Any idea if there's a short-cut to doing that change without copying the whole generic.xaml?

```
        <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TimePickerButtonForeground}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TimePicker">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="TimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="ElementSoundMode" Value="FocusOnly" />
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MinWidth="10" MaxWidth="150">
```

Comment: to explore and determine the right answer, I strongly recommend you to use [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf). You can select your app window and use something like Shift-click on your component to directly inspect the WPF components tree and their properties. You can then experiment to determine which exact target and properties should be "styled" as you need.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT No.

Answer (score 0):

Your imagine is correct, you could edit the `TimePicker`[`MinWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.minwidth?view=winrt-19041) property value like the following, and the default is `242`.

```
 <TimePicker MinWidth="100" x:Name="MyPicker" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" />
```

**Update**

I afraid you can't edit the 12HourClock style, because TimePicker will edit the style to hidden the am pm indicator in the code behind. So you want to edit the hour column with you need set  `ClockIdentifier`  as `12HourClock` and set `FirstTextBlockColumn` max with as you want value.

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="FirstTextBlockColumn" MaxWidth="20"/>
```

Comment: This will set the MinWidth for the full control. My problem is with the individual item container, like Hour, Minute size. Take a look at the picture.

Comment: Yes, I imagine this. I tried a couple of things, style, templates, but so far couldn't find what exactly to do.

Comment: could you share a picture that you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you see the picture above on my post? In one of the selectors there is "22" and in the other one is "00". As an example, you can see that the field where "22" is written is so wide that I could write "2222222222". I just want to shrink it (the width) to not waste all that space.

Comment: Which style that you have used ?